# Nginx Reverse Proxy - Modify custom header values if present

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to add different apps behind different locations of a reverse proxy.

I'm aware of the `proxy_redirect` directive which modifies the `Location` and `Refresh` headers, however I also need to modify custom headers like `X-Ajax-Redirect`.

I also tried my luck with the `map` directive but since this is even above the server level it doesn't work for different locations. I would need something like `sub_filter` that works for headers.

My current configuration:

```
worker_processes auto;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream docker-firstapp{
        server firstapp:8080;
    }

    upstream docker-secondapp{
        server secondapp:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location /myFirstApp/ {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-firstapp/;
            proxy_redirect     / /myFirstApp/;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

            sub_filter_once off;
            sub_filter ' href="/' ' href="/myFirstApp/';
            sub_filter ' src="/' ' src="/myFirstApp/';
            sub_filter ' action="/' ' action="/myFirstApp/';

            # sub_filter 'X-Ajax-Redirect: /' 'X-Ajax-Redirect: /myFirstApp/';
        }

        location /mySecondApp/ {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-secondapp/;
            proxy_redirect     / /mySecondApp/;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

            sub_filter_once off;
            sub_filter ' href="/' ' href="/mySecondApp/';
            sub_filter ' src="/' ' src="/mySecondApp/';
            sub_filter ' action="/' ' action="/mySecondApp/';

            # sub_filter 'X-Ajax-Redirect: /' 'X-Ajax-Redirect: /mySecondApp/';
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 1):

Proxy server take headers that you set for it and back with a response with its own headers

I don't know whether you want to

- send specific header for proxy {server > proxy}

or

- filters proxy responds before announcing to client {server > client}

so let's say we need both

---

**If server is communicating with proxy:** you would use `proxy_set_header`

you could set what header you want and send to the proxy

```
set $my_header "/myFirstApp/$x_ajax_redirect";
proxy_set_header X-Ajax-Redirect $my_header
```

> possible duplicate [Change Host header in nginx reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14352690/9907243)

---

**If server is communicating with client:**
nginx has the ability to add headers using [add_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html) directive

But it has 2 Limitations

1. It doesn't modify , means it only add headers.. so it could duplicate and conflict either nginx or browser
2. Restricted headers: means it only work with headers that nginx knows

**an alternative** is [headers-more-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module)

it allows for replacing, clearing default nginx headers
and setting either default or **custom** header

directive will look like this `more_set_headers 'X-Ajax-Redirect: ...';`

Documentations refers to some [limitations](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#limitations) but no problem as it could be used along with `add_header`

The only real limitation is that it's not part of nginx mainline
so you will need to compile it into nginx

**Installation**

1. Get nginx source code
2. Download the module from its [file list](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module/tags)
3. Build nginx from source with the module

```bsh
# download nginx source code
wget 'http://nginx.org/download/nginx-x.xx.x.tar.gz'
tar -xzvf nginx-x.xx.x.tar.gz
cd nginx-x.x.x/

# nginx installation dir: /opt/nginx/
# assuming you downdoaded the module
./configure --prefix=/opt/nginx \
    --add-module=/path/to/headers-more-nginx-module

# build nginx
make
make install
```

**Using docker ?**
You could find some nginx containers with this module compiled like [macbre/nginx-http3](https://hub.docker.com/r/macbre/nginx-http3)

> I will not recommend this container as it's built
> for expermental http3 features
>
> better to build from source or loading the module as a dynamic one